# cancel NSURLConnection in ios

Tags: ios, nsmutableurlrequest

I am calling webservice on `mapView` drag/regionChange. I want to keep some delay in the web service calls. So I want that whenever the user drags the map multiple times, all previous web service calls should be cancelled and only last drag web service call should be fired.

How do I do this?

Following is my code:

```
{ .... NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[data length]];

        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setHTTPBody:data];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSMutableDictionary __block *dictResponse;
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] cancelAllOperations];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

            if(connectionError == nil){

                dictResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&connectionError];
                }
```

Comment: Try AFNetworking by yourself at https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h . I think this is what you need

Comment: BTW, you never want to call `cancelAllOperations` on the main queue. It doesn't do what you intended here, and you have no assurances that some other task added some operation to the main queue. Also, you don't need to specify the `Content-Length` of your request, because that's done for you automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cancel a `sendAsynchronousRequest`. If you used a delegate-based `NSURLConnection` request, then you could cancel it, but (a) that's more coding than you probably want to bother with; (b) `NSURLConnection` is deprecated, so you should be `NSURLSession` anyway; and (c) `NSURLSession` allows you to cancel the task using the `NSURLSessionTask` reference that is returned to you:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"connection error = %@", error);
        return;
    }
    NSError *parseError;
    NSDictionary *responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&parseError];
    if (!responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"parse error = %@", parseError);
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // use response here; e.g., updating UI or model objects
    });
}];
[task resume];
```

If you need to cancel this request, just call `[task cancel]`. So save this `NSURLSessionTask` in some weak variable if you want to keep track of it and cancel it later.

Comment: it is great solution.

Comment: @Rob - I encountered another issue with this. When I cancel the session task and request again, I get error code -999 and the request is not made.

Comment: When you cancel a `NSURLSessionTask`, you should see the completion closure called with with error -999 (i.e. [`NSURLErrorCancelled`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes)). When you create a new `NSURLSessionTask`, the closure will be called a second time. Make sure you're not confusing that first response with the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `sendAsynchronousRequest` convenience API, use the main delegate API so you have access to the instance of `NSURLConnecyion` to call `cancel` on.

Also, don't cancel operations on the main queue, you don't know what's there, and consider using `NSURLSession`