# NSURLSessionTask cancel task and start a new request

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

So my query is linked with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33315590/cancel-nsurlconnection-in-ios).When I cancel the session task and request a new one, I get `error code -999` Following is my code:

```
    if(task.state == NSURLSessionTaskStateRunning){
        //        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10.0];
        [task cancel];
        NSLog(@"cancelled task");
    }
    //    [_progressBar setHidden:NO];

    task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            MSG_CONNECTION_ERROR;
                        [_progressBar setHidden:YES];

            return; //always returns
        }
//some code 
});
[task resume];
```

If you go through the link given above, I want to start a new request every time a user swipes `mapview`- new request call should be fired and previous one should get cancelled.

Where am I getting wrong? It was working fine previously but stopped when I tested the code in XCode 7.1.1.